# CSS IE hover issue with flyout menu

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7, flyout

I'm trying to create a CSS only menu that will work in IE7+ and FF. Of course, the menu currently works in IE8 and FF.

The problem is when you hover over `Store Departments > Women's Clothes > Grocery` and then just stop hovering (meaning, go directly from hovering over the `Grocery` to hovering over the document). Then hover over `Store Departments` again. What is happening is the 3rd level is still visible. It won't disappear correctly unless you hover over the 3rd level, then hover over the second level.

This issue only exists on IE7 and the dev URL is [navset.tabmin.com/vert.htm](http://navset.tabmin.com/vert.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to `hasLayout`:

http://murphy.cz/ie7-hover-ghosts-bug/

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Good old IE - web development would be really dull without it ;-)